# Is it possible to sync an ICS file with Mac's Calendar?

Tags: calendar, ical

I am trying to have a ICS that I generate on an hourly basis from third party calendar apps, which I would like to keep in sync with Mac's Calendar.

I haven't found a way to get Calendar to sync with an ICS file nor have I found the way to not import duplicated entries, which is a problem that exists, given that i will be syncing with the same calendar every time, only some items will be added.

If anybody has a solution for this, much appreciated!

Comment: I'm also looking for a solution to this, I am required to use a macbook and there is no way to sync it with my other syncthing static calendars. Have you made any progress?